# Why does service worker won't work on http sites?

Tags: javascript, security, https, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am learning about service worker API. I found more cool features in it. But what excites me is that **why it work only on https site and not on http site?**.

I believe this is something to do with security yet I couldn't find the reason while I browse. So any explanation explaining this is appreciated...

Comment: It's to ensure that the worker code itself is authentic.

Comment: Can you provide me an example of the bad cause when service worker was allowed to work on http site? I believe example or scenario explaining evil cause of it would help in better understanding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since service workers are rather powerful, being able to run even when the original page is no longer open, you'll really want to limit who can set up a service worker and who can't. Since a plain HTTP request is very easily [man-in-the-middled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), any random Javascript could be injected into such a request, which could set up a service worker. Which means, your ISP, a government like China, or a serious attacker could set up service workers very easily. By requiring an HTTPS connection, men-in-the-middle are largely avoided and you can at least assure that the Javascript that sets up the service worker actually came from the page you think it did.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation provided. Can you provide me an example of a man in the middle attack, if service worker is allowed in http site?

Comment: The man in the middle would be, for example, your ISP. It can see every single plaintext HTTP request and response, because it's relaying the data. Since it's relaying the data, it can also *change* the data. It could very simply add some additional Javascript into any HTML which could set up a service worker.

Comment: The ISP is a good example. Another example would be the router at an Internet cafe.

Comment: Ok. But what harm will it do the user, if attacker uses service worker api? If attacker do man in the middle and browser allowing those http sites, why not it allows service worker in http sites?

Comment: @Gopinath Again: a service worker is a trivial way to "install" a *permanent* piece of software into a user's browser. It doesn't even really matter what that software is able to really do; the idea alone of an unwanted 3rd party being able to install a **permanent** program is enough reason to disallow it. Crafty attackers will find ways to exploit that to their advantage one way or another. Even if they're just running infinite loops and burn CPU power, that alone would be disruptive.

Comment: Cool. This is what I was looking for (trivial way of installing software). Really appreciate the explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

To complement @deceze answer, if an attacker man-in-the-middle a connection to an HTTP site, it can compromises this site this time only — a later connection to the site is not guaranteed to be compromised, and for instance for attacks that rely on local network accesses, may not be easily reproductible.

If one could use a service worker on http web sites, an attacker needs to just do one man-in-the-middle attack to be forever (or at least until that browser is cleared) the source of the content for the said site.

Comment: Ok. But what harm will it do the user, if attacker uses service worker api? If attacker do man in the middle and browser allowing those http sites, why not it allows service worker in http sites?

Comment: Say you're surfing your favorite news web site on http:, and the attacker intercepts it one day on an open Wifi network, and set up a service worker: you'll never be able to get the real original web site from this browser if the attacker decides so.

Of course, you could be MiTM'd on http all the time as well, but service worker increases the duration and impact of a potential MiTM substantively.

Comment: Cool. Another best example. Really appreciate that